# How to store the data of a nested ListView and retrieve after , without a listmodel in qml

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have 3 nested `ListView`s.The first is the month, second is day and third is hour of day.All of them constructs a calendar.There is a loader that loads a window when I click in the hour  `ListView`, and set text  in a  `Label`.This text can be displayed in the hour view and can be deleted or edited through the above window .Unfortunately the text can not be saved because when I scroll the `ListView`s, delegates changing and not keeping the context of the label(That is normal I suppose).The objective is to be able to save those texts in the label(store the data) and restore them when the application is closed and re-opened.
Below is a generic code sample for 3 `ListView`s:

```
ApplicationWindow{
   id:appwindow
   ............
   Item{
    id:dayView
    ...........
    ListView{
       id:monthofdayCalendar
       orientation:Qt.Horizontal
       model:12
       delegate: Item{
       ListView{
        id:dayCalendar 
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        model:32
        delegate: Item{
        ...............
        ListView{
            id:daylistView
            orientation: Qt.Vertical
            model:24
            delegate:Item{
                 id:hourItem
                 property string hourTime:hourweeklistviewLabel
                 property string notetaking:notesLabe 
                 .............
                 MouseArea{
                      anchors.fill:parent
                      onClicked:{
                      windowLoader.active =true
                      daylistView.currentIndex=index

                      }
                 }  
                 Rectangle{}
                 Label{
                   id:hourweeklistviewLabel
                 }
                 Label{
                   id:notesLabel                                        
                   anchors.left:hourweeklistviewLabel.right
                   anchors.leftMargin: 30
                   text:""
                 }//Label
                }//delegate:Item
               }//ListView
              } //delegate:Item
             }//ListView
            }//delegate:Item
           }//Listview
          }//Item
```

Below is the code of loader:

```
Loader {
    id:windowLoader
    focus: true
    active:false
    sourceComponent: Window{
        id:inputWin
        title:"Enter Note"
        width:500
        height:300
        visible:true

        onClosing:{
            windowLoader.active=false
            monthofdayCalendar.currentItem.daycalendarAlias.currentItem.dayList.currentIndex = calendarMonth.selectedDate.getDate() === new Date().getDate()
                    && calendarMonth.selectedDate.getDay() === new Date().getDay()
                    && calendarMonth.selectedDate.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()?getHour():12


        }
        TextField {
            id:title
            x:50
            y:20
            placeholderText :'Enter Note'
            text:monthofdayCalendar.currentItem.daycalendarAlias.currentItem.dayList.currentItem.notetaking.text
        }
        TextField{
            id:timeDate

            anchors.horizontalCenter: title.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top:title.bottom
            anchors.topMargin:10
            placeholderText :  calendarMonth.selectedDate.getDate() +"-"
                   + (calendarMonth.selectedDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"
                   + calendarMonth.selectedDate.getFullYear() + " "
                   + monthofdayCalendar.currentItem.daycalendarAlias.currentItem.dayList.currentItem.hourTime.text
                }

            Button {
                 id: button
                 text: qsTr("Add Note")
                 anchors.centerIn:parent

                 onClicked: {
                       if (title.text !==""){monthofdayCalendar.currentItem.daycalendarAlias.currentItem.dayList.currentItem.notetaking.text= title.text}
                       else{}

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The big question is how to save (store) the data of `notesLabel.text` and be able to display it and restore it every time I close and re-open the application.
As you can see the model for each `ListView`  is not a `ListModel` so  I think I can not use those models to save the data if I am right.If I am wrong please advise.
Anyway your help will be appreciateed.

*******EDIT*******

I've changed the integer models with `ListModel` dynamically created.The code of the `ListModel`s is below:

```
                       ListModel{
                                  id:hourlistModel
                                  Component.onCompleted:{
                                      for (var i = 0; i <25; i++){
                                          append(createListElement())
                                      }
                                  }
                                    property int h:0
                                    function createListElement(){

                                        return {

                                            hour : h++
                                      }
                                    }
                                }
                       ListModel{
                            id:daylistModel
                            Component.onCompleted:{
                                for (var j=0; j <= 31; j++){
                                    append(createListElement())
                                }
                            }
                               property int dD:0
                               function createListElement(){

                                    return {

                                       day : dD++
                                      }
                                    }
                               }
                     ListModel{
                            id:monthlistModel
                            Component.onCompleted:{
                                for (var k=0; k <=11; k++){
                                    append(createListElement())
                                }
                            }
                            property int mN:0
                               function createListElement(){
                                    return {
                                       monthName : mN++
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
```

Can I store the data from `Label` notesLabel, now I've changed the models of `ListView`s with `ListModel`s?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct that you cannot use integer models to save data in this manner. Doing what you want requires a ListModel. Is there some reason you don't want to use one?

Comment: @fallerdNo, there is not a particular reason except that I do not know how to use one in my code.How to form the `ListElement`s.

Answer (score -1):

I would create an [exposed C++ class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html).

Using the exposed C++ class you have a range of options to pass data from the front/backend

- Q_Property/Member
- Q_Invokable
- Signal/Slots

Given that you are using strictly strings, I would use an exposed series of QStrings or a QStringList.

- QString
- QStringList

To tackle to file read/write use your now exposed C++ class. You can either stick to file I/O via standard c++ or [QFile system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html).

1. Constructor - Read the .txt file and save the data to your property data.
2. Exchange data as needed updating either the QML or C++ property member
3. Deconstructor - save the property member data back to file.

Brief example code:

someQML.qml
Import MyExposedClass 1.0

```
Item {
    
    MyExposedClass {
        id: myExposedClassID
        text: myExposedClassID
    }
    Text{
        id: yearTextID
        text: myExposedClassID.year
    }
    Text{
        id: monthTextID
        text: myExposedClassID.month
    }
    Text{
        id: dayTextID
        text: myExposedClassID.day
    }
    Button {
        id: myButtonID
        onButtonPressed {
            var finalStr = yearTextID + monthTextID + dayTextID
            // If you used a QMember of qstring lets say
            myExposedClassID.saveFile = finalStr

            // If you used a QInvokable
            myExposedClassID.saveFile_INVOK(finalStr)
        }
    }
}
```

myClass.h

```
class myClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    // Serial Dev
    Q_PROPERTY(QString day      READ getDay WRITE setDay NOTIFY dayChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString month    READ ... WRITE ... NOTIFY ...)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString year     READ ... WRITE ... NOTIFY ...)

...
    // On construction, read the text file and update the qproperty variables

    //implement getters and setters for qproperties

    // On deconstruction, write the properties to file
}
```

If you have issues with MVC and QStrings/QStringlist. You may have to look into QVariants or QAbstracts.

I find QML to be a risky hole to dive into. Its easy to add more and more functionality to a QML file. But if you try and redesign it or change up some logic, it can very quickly ruin the QML. Splitting the QML into a QML & C++ is a nice way to achieve modularity and control.